# Mysql - Check if spesific column of multiple rows are identical

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to check if a certain column value is the same across several rows?

I need to check if a customer has placed more than one order in my database.

If I do my select

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE email = 'customer@email.com'
```

This might yield

```
OrderID   Product   Amount   email
50        Apples    1        customer@email.com 
50        Oranges   1        customer@email.com
50        Bananas   1        customer@email.com
91        Apples    1        customer@email.com
```

So I need to check if OrderID is the same, across these rows.

But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use count() function and group by clause to caunt how many records you have by order id:

```
select email, orderid, count(*) as number_orders_per_orderid
from orders
where email = 'customer@email.com'
group by email, orderid
```

Or if you want to count the number of orders a user has made, then use count(distinct ...) with group by:

```
select email, count(distinct orderid) as number_of_orders
from orders
where email = 'customer@email.com'
group by email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with group by and having

```
select id, count(*) from orders group by id 
WHERE email = 'customer@email.com'
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a "Just one" if a customer has one ORDERID
You can get a "More than one"if a customer has more than one ORDERID using `CASE ... WHEN`

Here an example

```
SELECT email,COUNT(*) as number_order ,
(CASE WHEN count(*)=1 THEN "Just one" WHEN count(*)>1 THEN "More than one" END) AS number_order_status
FROM orders  GROUP BY email
```